# Is there a way to get informed when SQL Server updates a full text index

Tags: sql-server, full-text-indexing

I have a full text index on my SQL Server table with option `CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO`.

I can access the keywords and document IDs using the convenient `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document` system view.

My question is that can I get informed when a keyword is added or a new document is associated with an existing keyword ?

I tried to create an after insert trigger on `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document` but - not surprisingly - it is not allowed.

Regards,

Comment: you'd better to ask on DBA site: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you on?